# how to make a segment for matching in google analytic?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I want to get the most viewed pages in my webiste for a specific section. I am using filtering in Google Analytic to get the data but I need to make segments. In the screenshot you can see, that in the search fill I am searching for */health consumers/* in the reports and I got the result that I want but I don't know how to save it and use it again. I tried but I am not professional with Google Analytics.

Result I want
[image: Result I want] 
With the use of segment
[image: Segment window]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The (first) dimension you are filtering in the first screenshot is `Page`.

You have to use it: Filter `Sessions` `Include` **`Page`** `contains` */health_consumers/* in segment creation window you posted in the second screenshot.

Like this:
[image: Solution]

Comment: i cant find page in the list !!

Comment: @MohammadAlsaleh you have to type page in the field and scroll down a little. Check the screenshot above.